# MySQL Efficient Multi-Table Multi-Index Select

Tags: mysql, database, select, indexing

I want to search by name1 or name2 from two tables in a database.

IMPORTANT: Only some names have a secondary name2 associated with them.

The tables n1, and n2 are as follows:

```
table n1
|---------------*----------------*-----------------|
| id            | name1          | n2_id           |
|---------------*----------------*-----------------|
| 1             | Joseph         | 1               |
| 2             | David          | NULL            |
| 3             | James          | 2               |
|---------------*----------------*-----------------|

table n2
|---------------*----------------|
| id            | name2          |
|---------------*----------------|
| 1             | Joe            |
| 2             | Jim            |
|---------------*----------------|
```

(I know that I could have just created a name 2 field in the n1 table, however this is just a simplification of a more complex system that requires this structure.)

I currently select from table n1 as follows:

```
SELECT id, name1, MATCH ( name1 ) AGAINST ( "+joe*") AS score 
FROM n1 
WHERE MATCH ( name1 ) AGAINST ( "+joe*" in boolean mode) 
order by score desc;
```

This works very efficiently with a very large table.

However, I'd like to select from n1 and n2, MATCHING name1 or name2 (when it exists) against a search string as if both tables were combined.

The issue is that I have had problems with efficiency of a select that orders by a combined score when there are different indexes across multiple tables.

This question isn't really just about how to construct the SELECT.  It's about how to construct the SELECT in such a way that the indexes are used efficiently.  (the tables are very large)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
n1.id, name1, n2_id, n2.id, name2 
FROM n1 LEFT OUTER JOIN n2 ON
n2.id = n2_id 
WHERE name1 LIKE '%j%' OR name2 LIKE '%j%'
ORDER BY name1;
```

I used [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), due to

> "Only some names have a secondary name2 associated with them."

I combined two tables based on n2_id against id field in n2.

I used mysql [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) for String Comparison.

Here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0b0b/3)